# Faster function instead of using for loop several times, when checking trailing values after matching with indices

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, apply

I want to generate a binary variable [0,1] with some code that is faster then the example below. The scenario is like this:

If the value of variable mat$misst is equal to one (=1) (which is when C=1 and B= 2011), I want to check if some the trailing "facitar" (in this case 5) values is equal to zero (=0) and has the same value of variable A (A is indicating a person). if that is the case, mat$facit should be 1, otherwise zero (0).

My code below works, but the dataset I work with i very large (8,000,000 rows) so this code is taking ages...

```
A <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
B <- c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2009,2010,2011,2009,2010,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2014,2011,2012,2013,2014)
C <- c(1,1,1,1,99,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,99,1,1,1,0)
mat <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B,C))

facitar <- 5

mat$misst <- ifelse((mat$C==1 & mat$B==2011),1,0)
mat$facit <- 0

### code with for loop

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
  if(mat$misst[i]==1){
    for(j in (i+1):(i+facitar)){
      if(mat$C[j]==0 & mat$A[j]==mat$A[i]){
        mat$facit[i] = 1
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to work with `ifelse` and `apply` since they (i think?) work in a more efficient way, but I haven't figure out how I can get then to work in the same way as the for loop. Do someone have an idé? Thanks!

*ADDITION* (thanks to  ZF007)

Here is an attemp of using the `ifelse` command with a function containing a for loop (with I think will just be used on the values where the condition is true), to determine if the element is given 0 or 1. I'm not sure, but if this can get to work, this might be faster? or is it totally wrong?

```
mat$facit2 <- 0

func_facit <- function(){
  index_X01 <- which(mat$misst==mat$misst)
  for(j in (index_X01+1):(index_X01+facitar)){
    if(mat$C[j]==0 & mat$A[j]==mat$A[index_X01]){
      return(1)
      break
    } else{
      return(0)
    }
  }
}

mat$facit2 <- ifelse((mat$misst==1),func_facit,0)
```

But here i get the error:

```
Error in rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

Comment: These attempts you talk about ... post them into your question as well.. people can focus on these to fix. Now your question is just fit for the SO sister site "Code Review".

Comment: It would really help to see those previous attempts. Tried to see if I could do something, but right now it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. What are you trying to do? It seems you are wanting to operate on the person, so some type of splitting/grouping by person would achieve your goals faster than checking if the person is the same.

Comment: Sorry for my weak explanation, I've now added a an attempt with a "function" and "ifelse" command that did not work. But to add some comments of what I want to achieve:

Yes the goal is to operate on each person (variable A), and if the corresponding value of variable B=2011 and variable C=1 (in the example, element 1 fulfills these two criteria), I want to see if the 5 or more of the trailing value of C is 0 and the person (A) is the same (so element 1 dose not fulfills this criteria). As example, element 13 fulfills this criteria, as seen in the for loop example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I want to operate on each person that fulfills the criteria (when mat$misst==1, the same as variable B=2011 and variable C=1), maybe splitting the data into list of persons (A) might be some approach? If you come up with something i will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` and `any` to get the indexes where to set *facit* to 1

```
mat$facit[sapply(1:nrow(mat), function(i) {mat$misst[i]==1 && any(mat$C[i+1:facitar]==0 & mat$A[i+1:facitar]==mat$A[i])})] <- 1
```

As you want a binary variable you can set *facit* to `TRUE` or `FALSE` with:

```
mat$facit <- sapply(1:nrow(mat), function(i) {mat$misst[i]==1 && any(mat$C[i+1:facitar]==0 & mat$A[i+1:facitar]==mat$A[i])})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked really well and reduced the time significant.